# How to read candle data from a MetaTrader4 Terminal ( MT4 ) from vb.net in realtime

Tags: low-latency, candlestick-chart, mql4, metatrader4, mt4

I try to read data from MetaTrader 4 with my app ( on `vb.net` )

I catch data with **`DDE`** but it is only **`bid, ask, high, low`**. So I must try another way.

I want to read realtime data for finished candles ( **`M5`** and **`M15`** etc. )

How can I read realtime candle data from MetaTrader 4?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

### DDE-client pull-data mode

**`DDE`**-model allows external process to ask a DDE-server ( which may be enabled to run inside MT4 ) to respond to external request(s) independently of the other MetaTrader Terminal operations.

### MQL4 push-data mode

Much better control of the realtime performance, scope and other features one may achieve by active push-data policy, where MetaTrader Terminal software operates it's internal **`MQL4`**-code-execution-factory, which runs appropriate push-data facilitation towards any external process.

`MQL4` language distinguishes several modes of operation:

Each graph in MT4 may be associated with **one** so called **`Expert Advisor`** <sub>coded in MQL4 language</sub>

Each graph in MT4 may be associated with **several** **`Custom Indicators`** <sub>other MQL4 programme(s)</sub>

Each graph in MT4 may be associated with **one `Script`** <sub>a third type of MQL4 programme</sub>

Using this, one may fulfill any kind of live-export needs, including a low-latency, real-time data publication of an `OHLCV+T` + actual `Ask - Bid` ( a.k.a. spread ) data for a just closed `Bar` ( be it `M1`, `M5`, `M15` or any other form of synthetic time-framing of the market events' flow ).

### Principle

`MQL4` programs use syntactically a c-class programming language ( be carefull, `MQL4` does not mimick `c-lang` and is specific in many ways, but is equipped with almost all syntax-constructors you may expect in `c-lang` ).

Conceptually, your **`Expert Advisor`** type-of-code may export any data, based on one condition that all programs of this type expect ... it must receive a message from FOREX Market ( from MetaTrader Server, operated on your Broker side ) about a "new"-`QUOTE` ( a.k.a. a tick ). Upon such event, your code gets control via an **`OnTick(){...}`** function an there you go, you may do whatever reasonable for your intended exports.

In case you want to use a **`Script`-model**, there you need not wait till Monday start of the FOREX Markets, because this type of code gets control once it is initiated via an **`OnStart(){...}`** function, without any synchronicity with Market Events' flow.

Your `MQL4` code can even co-operate with DLL-published API services, so technically speaking only your's imagination is the potential limit.

### Further reading

> MQL4 Reference / MQL4 programs
>
> MQL4 Reference / Language Basics
>
> MQL4 Reference / Language Basics / Functions / Description of External Functions
>
> MQL4 Reference / Language Basics / Object-Oriented Programming / Polymorphism